# Name-Based Virtual Hosting to identify different SSL virtual hosts on Ubuntu Apache LAMP Server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, namespaces, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

Is it not possible to use Name-Based Virtual Hosting to identify different SSL virtual hosts?

I am trying to implement https: for multiple websites on my Ubuntu 10.04 server, but I came across this resource which tells me it cannot be done:

http://www.linuxpoweruser.com/?p=121

The workaround given in this HowTo is suggesting that I have a site structure like this:

```
www.abc.com/site1
www.abc.com/site2
www.abc.com/site3
```

This is not a satisfactory workaround for me.  Can someone tell me whether there is a better workaround for this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to run everything on the same IP address, you have multiple options:

- Use a wildcard certificate `*.example.com`. This will be valid for `www1.example.com` and `www2.example.com`, but not for `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com1`. [The wildcard must be in the left-most label](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3). Wildcard certificate usage is [discouraged](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-1.5).
- Use a single certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names (SANs). You could then have a SAN for `www.example1.com` and another one for `www.example2.com` (the names don't need to be related).
- Use multiple certificates and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI). The downside is that [not all clients support it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#No_support) (especially IE on Windows XP, as far as I'm aware).

If you can use multiple IP addresses, simply use one certificate per IP-address.

Answer (score 0):

You can *only* use name-based hosts with SSL if they're using the same certificate, because the SSL negotiations happen before the `Host` header is actually transferred.

So, *if* you have different hosts in one domain, like `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`, `c.example.com`, then you can use them with the `*.example.com` wildcard certificate. Otherwise there's no workaround.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I will be using the same certificate for each site, but I don't have different hosts in one domain as in your example.  I have about 5 completely different domains that I am trying to configure for https.  Can this be done?

Comment: @Bruno, one day it will be practical solution.

Comment: @DanielAttard, if you generate certificate yourself, then, as Bruno points out you can use alternative names. I'm not sure how it works with cert authorities. But that would mean you'll have to regenerate certificate every time you add host. The point is — you only can have one certificate, go from that.

Comment: Multiple SANs have been generally well supported for a while. I'm not sure what the procedure with CAs is, though.

Comment: @Bruno, yes, sorry, I was referring to SNI.

Comment: One more quite unpractical thing that can be done — using different certificates on different ports. But that would make URLs ugly and would make it unusable for public sites, may work for something private.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SSL certificate for every Virtual Host (that is for every website or domain or subdomain) that you host on your server, the only thing that you should take into consideration is to point every Vhost certificate key and crt to the correct location of those file on your filesystem. If you want to use multiple SSL Virtual Hosts with custom Self-Signed Certificates for every Virtual host on Ubuntu, you can consult this guide http://www.bytelinux.com/create-self-signed-certificates-enable-apache-ssl-ubuntu-14-10/